# Abstracting threading and multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a module that abstract threading and multiprocessing in Python? I want to have an option of switching between them in future.

Comment: Are you worried about the fact that the interfaces are only 95% compatible instead of 100%, or do you think you need some kind of Interface/Protocol/AbstractBaseClass to abstract things as you would in, say, Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `threading` and `multiprocessing` module already use a similar interface for this. The multiprocessing actually falls back to the `threading` module if it isn't supported.

You can use an `import multiprocessing as something` and `import threading as something` to switch between the two unseen.

**Note that data sharing between the two is different and this might create potential pitfalls.** As noted by jdi

Comment: **bold** on the last statement. You would have to stick to just using `Process` and avoid some of the shared data containers since threading doesn't have managers. `Process` shares the same api as `Thread`

Comment: The other problem is that, even when you avoid data sharing and do everything via messages (queues, or job startup params and return values, or whatever), `multiprocessing` can only handle picklable values. It's almost always worth writing the code for `multiprocessing` first if you're not sure which one you'll want in the end.